# sesiones php al cerrar el navegador

Tags: session

Parece que no he comprendido del todo bien como funcionas las sesiones en PHP, tengo entendido que son variables que se quedan "fijas" en el servidor de tal forma que cuando uno crea sesiones al usar el navegador y luego cerrar el mismo entonces al volver a abrir el navegador (sin que pase mucho tiempo) las sesiones aún están vivas y se pueden volver a consultar a usar.
Pues bien tengo una página web simple que hice en PHP, html, jquery, css que es una tiendita en línea: https://countier.com.mx/tienditadegaba/index.php

Ahí puedo elegir unos productos e irlos agregando al carrito de compra.
Cuando cierro la ventana del navegador (uso mac) y vuelvo a entrar a la misma página veo que el carrito todavía está vivo y con los productos que elegí, sin embargo cuando cierro por completo el navegador al 100% y vuelvo a entrar al sitio, resulta que el carrito de compra ahora si está vacio, las variables de sesión se destruyeron, ya no existen.

No sé si esto es funcionamiento del nevegador en MAC o algo no estoy entendiendo bien. ¿Alguna alma caritativa que me pueda orientar?
Gracias.

Ejemplo:

"

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['nombre']='Ivan';

    echo "El valor de la variable de session 'nombre' es:".$_SESSION['nombre'];
?>
```

"

Si este pequeño script lo ejecuto funciona bien y me muestra el valor de la variable 'nombre' "Ivan", sin embargo cuando cierro por completo el navegador y ahora ejecuto otro archivo con el siguiente script, el valor de la variable de session 'nombre' está vacio y no entiendo porque, tenía entendido que las sessiones no se morían.

```
            <?php
                session_start();
                echo "El valor de la variable de session 'nombre' es:".$_SESSION['nombre'];
            ?>
```

Comment: Hola. Veo que ya has formulado preguntas antes. Recuerda que tu pregunta debe incluir un ejemplo mínimo verificable y el enlace no lo es, pues no podemos ver el código (y si la página es eliminada en el futuro, tu pregunta y la respuesta no servirán a nadie).

Comment: Lee este link https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php y busca info sobre el funcionamiento de cookies y navegadores, cuando tengas una duda más específica la formulas acá.

Comment: Si cierras el navegador y tienes configurado que se borren las cookies al cerrar, no va a haber cookie que le diga a la página que tenías una sesión antes... o si el servidor está configurado para borrar sesiones inactivas después de N segundos, así tengas cookie no habrá sesión asociada y te creará una nueva sin los datos que habías creado antes. Depende.

Answer (score 0):

Dejame ver si entendí bien..
Aunque no uso mac, en Windows puedes cerrar una pestaña y el navegador continúa guardando la información de sesión guardada, sin embargo, al cerrar completamente el navegador, la memoria se libera y los datos de sesión son eliminados. Por eso siempre se recomienda cerrar sesión antes de cerrar el navegador.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es que se la sesión se cierre al cerrar la pestaña, puedes crear un destructor para la variable de sesión que se active después de cierto tiempo de inactividad en ella, pueden ser 5 min o 10 min. Algo así.

Espero haber entendido bien.

Comment: Una pregunta muy amplia sólo permite respuestas muy amplias. Con suficiente rep, puedes añadir comentarios para pedir info adicional.

Comment: En realidad lo que espero es que las sessiones quedan vivas cuando se cierre por completo el nevegador, incluso aunque se apague la computadora, según yo ese es el chiste de las sesiones, que tu información de ese momento quede viva durante un momento aunque cierres todo o incluso apagues

Comment: @IvanCaballeroCano Tienes que hacer uso de cookies para que las sesiones duren x tiempo hasta cuando el dispositivo se apague https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.cookies.php